# Avoiding jagged text when pasting into vi?

Tags: vim, appliance, busybox

Although I have no problem using SecureCRT (5.1.2 build 274) to work from Windows and connect to PC's running Linux, I have a problem when connecting to an embedded Asterisk appliance that provides"vi" through BusyBox 1.4.1 (2008-03-10).

The issue I'm having, is that when I paste code into vi, the text appears jagged like this:

```
<?php                                                                                                                               
try {                                                                                                                               
        $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:./db.sqlite");                                                                                       
                $dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255))");
```

Does someone what the problem is? Is there a way to reconfigure either BusyBox or SecureCRT so that I can paste successfully?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is vi's auto-indent conflicting with the existing indentation. Activate paste mode before pasting.

```
<ESC>:set paste
```

NB: I usually use vim. It is possible that the feature doesn't exist in vi.

Comment: I'm guessing when he said `vi` he actually meant `vim`. I cant think of any reason why people still using `vi` when backwards-compatible, superior and awesome `vim` is around.

Comment: He also mentioned BusyBox, which suggests an extremely limited (in RAM and CPU) environment (such as a consumer grade router).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but ":set paste" doesn't work on this minimal vi as part of BusyBox :-/ I'll see if I can recompile a newer version to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you have `smartindent` or `autoindent` turned on.  I used to do `set si!` and `set ai!`, but David Dorward's answer seems to have the same effect.  (I'll have to remember that one.  :) )

I think `set ai` is the only one in vanilla `vi`.  If you want to *force* it to turn off, do `set noai` (`set ai!` just flips the state.)